# How do I build a dynamic query in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to build a query using the following sample data:

```
{
   brandFilters:[ { brand: 'Amana', checked: true },
     { brand: 'Whirlpool', checked: true } ],
   priceFilters:[ { low: 100, high: 200, label: '$100 - $200', checked: true },
     { low: 200, high: 300, label: '$200 - $300', checked: true } ],
  rating: null }
```

The first segment of the query builds the brands criteria as shown here;

```
let brands = [];
let productQuery = Product.find();

if(filters.brandFilters.length) {
    for(let filter of filters.brandFilters) {
        brands.push(filter.brand)
    }

    productQuery.where('brand').in(brands)
    console.log('brands', brands)    
}
```

The second segment is supposed build the price criteria as shown here:

```
if(filters.priceFilters.length) {
    for(let filter of filters.priceFilters) {
        productQuery.where('price').gte(+filter.low).lte(+filter.high);
    }
}
```

The intention is to add a "where" clause for each price filter as shown in the data above. The problem is multiple where clauses for the price criteria are not being added. Each successive price filter in the for loop overwrites the last. So instead of having multiple "where" clauses for my price filters, the query only contains one for the last iteration of the for loop.

I am trying to get to a query that would look like this:

```
productQuery.where('brand').in(['Amana', 'Whirlpool'])
productQuery.where('price').gte(100).lte(200)
productQuery.where('price').gte(200).lte(300)
```

Comment: FWIW, I haven't seen many sites that allow a filter on multiple price ranges.  The example you give for a thing you'd want should just be `productQuery.where('price').gte(100).lte(300)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the query you're trying to build should look like below:

```
{
    "$and":[
        {"$or":[
            {"price":{"$gte":100,"$lte":200}},
            {"price":{"$gte":200,"$lte":300}}
            ]
        },
        {"brand":{"$in":["Amana","Whirlpool"]}}
    ]
}
```

So it contains `$or` to include multiple price ranges. To do that you can build that query as plain JavaScript object and then pass it to `find` method, try:

```
let query = {
    '$and': []
};

var priceQuery = [];
let brands = [];

if(filters.priceFilters.length) {
    for(let filter of filters.priceFilters) {
        priceQuery.push({ 'price': { $gte: +filter.low, $lte: +filter.high } });
    }

    query['$and'].push({ '$or': priceQuery });
};

if(filters.brandFilters.length) {
    for(let filter of filters.brandFilters) {
        brands.push(filter.brand)
    }

    query['$and'].push({ 'brand': { '$in': brands } });
}
```

and then

```
let products = await Product.find(query);
```

Comment: I can't find any documentation that mongoose has a feature to build query easier, Anyone?